# How to set default child-state with UIRouter angular.io

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ui-router

How can i set as default a child state with ui-router and angular.io?
I have a section about, with some child-states. What i want to do is that when i go in the about section, by default it renders the first child state.

Comment: its for angular ?? https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/interfaces/state.ng2statedeclaration.html#redirectto

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect for default child route like this:

```
{
path: 'course',
component: CourseComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: CourseListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'taking',
    component: TakingCourseComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'list',  // this work like as default custom route. 
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
 ]
},
```